# SDE and elliptic operators

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-differential-equations

Say $X$ is the solution of a SDE, stopped at the exit time from a bounded domain $D\subset R^d$. This means that given some filtered probability space where $B$ is a $d$-dimensional brownian motion, and $\sigma:\mathbb{R}^d\to \mathbb{R}^{d \times d}$, $b:\mathbb{R}^d\to\mathbb{R}^d$ measurable functions, one has
$$ X=x_0+\int_0^t \sigma(X_s) dB_s + \int_0^t b(X_s) ds$$
for all $t \leq \tau$ where $\tau=\inf\{t>0: X_t \notin D\} \lt \infty $ a.s.

Suppose now that $F$ is a $\mathcal{C}^2$ on $D$ and that it satisfies $LF=0$ in $D$, where

$$ LF(x):= \frac{1}{2} \sum_{i,j \leq d} a_{i,j}(x) \frac{\partial^2 F}{\partial{x_i}\partial{x_j}}(x)+\sum_{i=0}^d b_i(x)\frac{\partial F}{\partial x_i}$$
where $A=\sigma \sigma^t$

This is where my problems begin: according to my notes, one can see using Ito's formula that $F(X^{\tau}_t)$ is a local martingale since the other terms vanish because $LF=0$ and $d\langle X^i, X^j \rangle = a_{i,j}(X_t)dt$. I don't understand why the latter equality holds and in general would be grateful to anyone who could show me this computation with Ito's formula.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The latter equality simply holds because, due to the SDE that $X$ satisfies,
\begin{align}
\langle X^i,X^j\rangle_t&=\left\langle\sum_{k=1}^d\int_0^.\sigma_{ik}(X_s)\,dB^k_s,\sum_{l=1}^d\int_0^.\sigma_{jl}(X_s)\,dB^l_s\right\rangle_t\\
&=\sum_{k,l=1}^d\left\langle \int_0^.\sigma_{ik}(X_s)\,dB^k_s,\int_0^.\sigma_{jl}(X_s)\,dB^l_s\right\rangle_t\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^d\int_0^t\sigma_{ik}(X_s)\sigma_{jk}(X_s)\,ds\\
&=\int_0^ta_{ij}(X_s)\,ds\,.
\end{align}

Comment: Thanks, this is already really helpful. I still don't understand where the $LF=0$ kicks in though, is the bounded variation term cancelling with the second derivatives? If you ever find the time of writing it down, please do it, it would help me a lot, I never saw one computation of this kind in its entirety.

Comment: If you apply Ito's formula to a function $F$ that satisfies $LF=0$ you will see that only the $dB$-terms remain. Hence $F(X)$ is a local matringale. The stopped $F(X)$ is also a local martingale (optional stopping theorem).

Comment: Isn't the incarnation of Ito's formula one should use the one involving $dX$ and $d\langle X_i,X_j \rangle$? $X$ is in general a seminartingale right? So $X=x_o + M + V$ where M is a local martingale and $V$ a bounded variation term. Will the $dB$ terms you talk about arise from using the fact that $X$ is a solution of an SDE?

Comment: If by 'the one' you mean [this one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/It%C3%B4_calculus#It%C3%B4's_lemma) : Yes . You know what $dX$ is (your SDE) and I showed you why that covariation is what it is . So please -shut up and calculate: just apply Ito to $F(X_t)$. Never mind: that harsh sounding quote is from a famous physicist. Not meant to be an insult. :)